# a parser application which can implement xml files and run accordingly

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I want to implement an application which will work as a parser. User will be able to upload xml files which will describe UI and functional properties of some android application. I wonder if there is already a way to parse xml files and use them  as layouts without compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're parser will have to generate new Views which receive "parameters" via the xml files. Afterwards you'd have to add the Views progammatically to your layout root.

It doesn't really matter which parser technology you are using for this purpose as you're going to create objects from it - so SAX, DOM & Pull-Parser would all be suitable.